# Progressbar - How to add timer?

Tags: python, progress-bar

I am using the [progressbar module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar) (version 2.3), and it is all working great:

[image: progressbar]

I am calling it by doing this:

```
for row in pbar(rows):
```

Sometimes, the task can take several minutes and what I really want is a timer saying how long has passed and how long is remaining. Does anyone have an easy way of doing this? I have seen some of the examples and I am getting confused.

Comment: 'the progressbar module', is that [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar),
 or perhaps [`progressbar2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2)?

Comment: If you are using [progressbar2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2), there is an example in the end that uses `ETA`.

Comment: @CarlesMitjans: the other package also supports ETAs.

Comment: I think it is just progressbar, I am not sure how to check to be honest

Comment: I found an ETA page (thank you for telling me what I need to look for), but I am kinda looking to wrap the iterable rather than a seperate module. I guess it is a case of beggers cant be chooser?

Comment: @ScoutEU: how did you install it? Does `pip freeze` list the package?

Comment: Didnt know about pip freeze, thanks! It says "progress bar 2.3"

Comment: Perfect, fixed it!... I installed the latest progress bar and it is working now (after using the links you provided) :)... ty guys

Comment: @ScoutEU: sounds like you can self-answer now.

Comment: Thank you, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was that I was using 'Progressbar 2.3' and not 'Progressbar2 3.3' which meant the code I was trying to run was not working.

I installed the latest progress bar and using this:

```
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[
    ' [', progressbar.Timer(), '] ',
    progressbar.Bar(),
    ' (', progressbar.ETA(), ') ',
])
```

And wrapping my iterable like this:

```
for row in bar(rows):
```

Worked exactly the way I wanted:
[image: progressbar2]